# What's the purpose of the hash added to filenames in custom folder?

Tags: 4.6.8

I have a ton of image files to add to Civi (far too many to do manually) and have figured out what tables to update & make it all work.  But I notice that files uploaded via the Civi UI have a hash string added to the filename that's stored.  So xyz.pdf becomes xyz$$$.pdf where $$$ is the hash. What's the purpose of this hash string?  Is it to make a unique URI?  Should I do this as well for my files? It all works without this.  (I don't want to use the API by the way, and we're on 4.6.8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two reasons I can think of:

- what happens if you upload twice a file with the same name for different contacts? the hash allow to avoid overwriting
- probably increase a bit the protection and privacy too, eg. by guessing and trying to download warren_buffet.jpg or bill_gates.jpg, we could know if you have some wealthy donors in your db

This being said, it's been there since forever and I never quite questioned it.

If it's for mass uploading contact images, you can probably just set the field into civicrm_contact and put the image at the right place, I remember having done something like that a while ago, it probably still works

as andy detailled, you need to touch a few more tables if you want to upload the file in a custom field

- add a row to civicrm_file with the file name
- add a row to civicrm_entity_file to link to the contact id, civicrm_file table & your custom table
- update your custom table with the numeric id from the civicrm_file
- upload the file into the right folder

Comment: Thanks, Xavier, I will add a unique hash key.  For others to know, you have to 1) add a row to civicrm_file with the file name 2) add a row to civicrm_entity_file to link to the contact id, civicrm_file table & your custom table 3) update your custom table with the numeric id from the civicrm_file 4) upload the file.  QED!

Comment: ah, i replied about the contact thumbnail, but indeed, slightly more complicated if custom field. i'm updating my answer with your extra info

Answer (score 0):

If you are spending time trying to manually reproduce how Civi handles files in your own custom code, consider using the Attachment api, which will do it all for you:

[image]